# Schedule querys with Python psycopg2

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, raspberry-pi, psycopg2

I would like to query data form a PostgreSQL database every 5 minutes, I was thinking about using psycopg2 to query a SELECT every five minutes and using time.sleep() to wait those 5 minutes, all inside a `while true` loop. This will be running in a raspberry pi. I was wondering if there was a better way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cron might be more efficient here, to trigger the func call every 5 rather than leaving open and running persistently in stasis. Do you expect the query to finish in under 5 minutes consistently?

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md 
https://crontab.guru/every-5-minutes

There's all you need to schedule a task every 5m. Cron has a little language or formula all its own but is extremely powerful, will execute any command-line task at any interval to the minute. It's kind of like a command-line calendar for recurring tasks. And if your task only takes 5s, it leaves your system idle for the remaining 4m 55s in between for other processes you may want to install to run cleanly.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I kind of new to SQL and IoT, its gonna be a small database, up to 7000 rows so I will expect it to finish in less than 5 minutes, I'll be calling a procedure to find new logs in the local database and upload them to SQLServer